# Float: right not working properly in Firefox addon Code

Tags: html, css, firefox, firefox-addon

I am working with a Firefox add-on in which i need a button in the right of a panel for which i am using the `float:right` style attribute but when i use this attribute the button aligns right and the text area located under it disappears however when i run the code without the float right attribute the code works fine.

Here is the code where i have used the float right attribute.

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
      textarea {
        margin: 2% 5%;
        width:90%
      }
    </style>
  </head>

<body>
    Email Arrieved 
    <input type="button" id ="clearall" value="Respond" style="float: right;>
    <textarea rows="4" id="edit-box" ></textarea>
  </body>

</html>
```

Desired output is that i should be that the text with the button should be left align and the button should be right aligned with the text-area located under them.

Am coding for an addon in Firefox so is there some specific function to do this or there is something wrong with the css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close the style attribute value. Is that it ? Looks fine here.

```css
      textarea {
        margin: 2% 5%;
        width:90%
      }
```

```html
    Email Arrieved 
    <input type="button" id ="clearall" value="Respond" style="float: right";>
    <textarea rows="4" id="edit-box" ></textarea>
```